# Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I am running 64bit Ubuntu 13.04

I tried to install cairo-dock

executed these command :

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa` - went well, no error.
- `sudo apt-get update` - went well, no error.
- `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins` - error.

This is the process in the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
The following extra packages will be installed: cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data cairo-dock-plug-ins-data cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration compiz-plugins curl libetpan15 libgldi3 Suggested packages: cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-mono cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-ruby cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-vala gnote 
The following NEW packages will be installed: cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data cairo-dock-plug-ins cairo-dock-plug-ins-data cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration compiz-plugins curl libetpan15 libgldi3 
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 10.3 MB of archives. After this operation, 26.7 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
Get:1 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-data all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [468 kB] 
Get:2 **link** raring/universe libgldi3 amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [352 kB] 
Get:3 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-core amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [1,125 kB] 
Get:4 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-data all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [4,190 kB] 
Get:5 **link** raring-updates/main curl amd64 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1 [149 kB] 
Get:6 **link** raring/universe libetpan15 amd64 1.0-5 [286 kB] 
Get:7 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [871 kB] 
Get:8 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [59.9 kB] 
Get:9 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [16.0 kB] 
Get:10 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [8,738 B] 
Get:11 **link** raring-updates/universe compiz-plugins amd64 1:0.9.9~daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 [2,764 kB] Fetched 10.3 MB in 2min 1s (84.8 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package cairo-dock-data. dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19': Input/output error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The install hasn't completed. It's stuck on dpkg. This error occurs everytime I try to install a program using apt-get install.

The link: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

The error.

***unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:***
-> ***reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19': Input/output error***
--> ***E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)***

The verdict.

Input / Output error means that the media is bad. Use another CD, download the package, or replace your hard drive (it could be just a filesystem error).

If the problem is indeed with your hard drive, further indications thereof will be in the kernel log. Run `dmesg` to look at it. Look for suspicious, technical-looking lines starting with "ata" or "sdX".

Comment: what do you mean about technical-looking lines? I have this output : ata1:SATA, ata2:DUMMY ata3:DUMMY ata4:DUMMY and so on.. I run dmesg |grep -i ata

Comment: [techical-looking lines](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-563363.html), [another example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51241/disk-errors-on-tty-and-syslog-dmesg)

Comment: I have not seen any of those lines when I run dmesg..